# Getting video lengths in Laravel

Tags: laravel, video, laravel-4, laravel-5

Does anyone know how you get get video lengths in laravel (preferably in the validator)?

I know its possible to check for video extension and the file size but I want to get the actual length of the video too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't support video length natively, but you can extend the Validation functionality to create your own rule. But you'll need to rely on a library to determine the video length:

```
// Rule
$rules = [
    'video' => 'required|file|video_length:5000',
];

// Custom validation rule
Validator::extend('video_length', function( $attribute, $value, $parameters ) {
    $length = 0; // check length using library
    return $length <= $parameters[0];
});
```

You'll need to upload the video to your server. Check the length of the video using the library of your choice and return error if it exceeds your restrictions.

The [ID3 library](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

With using [ID3 library](http://getid3.sourceforge.net)

```
$getID3 = new \getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($video_path);
$duration = date('H:i:s.v', $file['playtime_seconds']);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955402/how-to-get-duration-a-video-laravel)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).