# How to validate video duration in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate video with a duration <= 30 seconds in laravel controller in a statamic addon (I don't know if this is an important detail).

Here's the custom validator using GetID3

```
Validator::extend('VideoLength', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            // validate the file extension

            if(!empty($value->getClientOriginalExtension()) && ($value->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'mp4')){

                //new GetId3() expected an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile

                $track = new GetId3($value);
                $track->extractInfo();
                $duration = $track->getPlaytime();
                return(round($duration) > 30) ?false:true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },'Video duration must be less then 30 seconds');
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
 Owenoj\LaravelGetId3\GetId3::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile given
```

Comment: I think this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073083/getting-video-lengths-in-laravel

Comment: I've already seen it thank you, but my problem is in the conversion of UploadedFile it has to be an instance of  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile but it's an instance of Symfony\Compopnent

Answer (score 1):

Try it using a custom closure rule. I used it without issues before. Also use the `mimetypes` rule to limit the file types.

```php
request()->validate([
    'video' => [
        'required',
        'mimetypes:video/mp4',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $video = new GetId3($value);

            if ($video->getPlaytimeSeconds() > 30) {
                $fail('The video must be shorter than 30 seconds.');
            }
        }
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I've tried what you've done same error :/
`Type error: Argument 1 passed to Owenoj\LaravelGetId3\GetId3::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile given`

Comment: That's odd. Because I tried a `dd(request()->video` and the dumped object was an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`. Which Laravel version are you using? And where are you trying to perform the validation? Also how are you uploading the file from the front end?